# AnitForgeryToken with Web Api in ASP.net 5

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using the new ASP.net 5 Web Application and Web Api templates (I've created two seperate applications).

- App 1 is going to be a Single Page Application (SPA) and pull its
  data from App 2.
- App 2 is a Web Api, it will server data to App 1.

Nothing crazy in this approach so far.  When I chose to build an SPA, I was stepping away from what I'd traditionally do with MVC.  But I like some MVC features, in particular the AntiForgeryToken security (security is very important to me).

What I am planning to do is have my initial index page (App 1) loaded via MVC (so have a index.cshtml and controller).  Then write my antiforgerytoken onto the index page when its delivered to the client.  At that point Angular takes over and all my calls will be to App 2.  I was going to pass the AntiForgeryToken to each service call so it can be verified BUT i have a feeling it wont work because I generated it within App 1 (who will now be expecting it) and App 2 wont know anything about this.

Approach is outlined in my terrible diagram below:

[image]

1. Firstly, is my assumption correct?  - I wont be able to use the AntiForgeryToken on the web app because this app didnt generate it?
2. Secondly, is a better approach to remove MVC from the equation in App 1, and instead create a web api controller method (in App 2), that will generate me a token on the web api, then I can get it and keep track of that in Angular in App 1 - passing it to each request going back to App 2?
3. OR is there a better way (I am using Angular after all)
4. OR is this just pointless? :-)

Thanks for advice!

Comment: We have literally just done this same exact thing! We wrapped the front-end application (AngularJS) inside of the index.cshtml. The api methods are decorated with [AntiForgeryValidate]. We as well had to add an Angular directive. Here is the link: http://blog.novanet.no/anti-forgery-tokens-using-mvc-web-api-and-angularjs/

Comment: Hi Mike, this is excellent!! So glad to hear I was working along the same lines as you guys!  Just one thing - the MVC app (in my case app 1), requests the anti forgery token from the web api? (that's what the helper is for in your case?) or is that fine to come from the normal MVC app 1 and pass over to app 2?

Comment: I should have mentioned, I'm using ASP.net 5 and the code in your link doesn't work for it unfortunately.